# How to overcome UINavigation Controller pop view controller animation using storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I stuck into some strange problem.I am using storyboard to create the navigation controller based application.I am supporting portrait and landscape orientations.I am passing a data in between view controllers with segue.The problem is here if application is running in portrait  if i go inside navigation controller stack view controllers like

Home---push---> viewcontroller1 -----push----> viewcontroller2 -----push----> viewcontroller 3.

If i pop from viewcontroller 3 to view controller 2 (or viewcontroller 2 to view controller 1) in portrait it poping with perfect navigation bar animation (Right to left).

The main problem is with landscape

If i pop from viewcontroller 3 to view controller 2 (or viewcontroller 2 to view controller 1) in landscape it poping with perfect navigation bar animation (top to bottom).

why it is not pop right to left ...please tell me what is the problem with it.
I have tried with segue connections and so many other ways .But no luck.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray got the solution guys.It is because of these two methods.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

I just removed these two methods and working like a charm.